# Cannot resolve setImageUrl

Tags: java, android

> "Hi everyone, I am working on the volley with recyclerviw. However, I spent a long time to figure out a bug. In this part:
>
> viewHolder.giftPicture.setImageUrl(IMAGE_URL, mImageLoader);
>
> I don't know why it keeps saying 'Cannot resolve setImageUrl', it works in my other parts of code. Can anyone help me? Thanks."

```
public class NavigationRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NavigationRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Gift> mGifts;
    ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    private static final String IMAGE_URL = "http://media2.intoday.in/indiatoday/images/stories/google-doodle-story_647_032416125016.jpg";

    NavigationRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Gift> gifts) {
        mGifts = gifts;
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view, viewGroup, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        Gift gift = mGifts.get(i);
        viewHolder.giftTitle.setText(gift.title);
        viewHolder.currentPrice.setText(gift.currentPrice);

        // Get the ImageLoader through your singleton class.
        mImageLoader = MySingleton.getInstance(mContext).getImageLoader();

        // Set the URL of the image that should be loaded into this view, and
        // specify the ImageLoader that will be used to make the request.
        viewHolder.giftPicture.setImageUrl(IMAGE_URL, mImageLoader);
//        viewHolder.giftPicture.setImageResource(R.drawable.userimg);


        viewHolder.giftTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Context context = view.getContext();
                context.startActivity(new Intent(context, AddGiftsActivity.class));`enter code here`
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mGifts.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

//        private final TextView mTextView;
        CardView mCardView;
        TextView giftTitle;
        TextView currentPrice;
        ImageView giftPicture;

        ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mCardView = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            giftTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.gift_title);
            currentPrice = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.current_price);
            giftPicture = (NetworkImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.gift_picture);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: need to cast ImageView to NetworkImageView

Comment: or set giftPicture as NetworkImageView in viewholder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ImageView does not has a setImageUrl method you need to either cast giftPicture as NetworkImageView while calling Uri or change

> ImageView giftPicture;

to

> NetworkImageView giftPicture;

in ViewHolder

Comment: Thanks a lot. I change giftPicture to cast to NetworkImageView in the findViewByID, but didn't change in the variable declaration. That's the problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: The class NetworkImageView is now called "ANImageView"